# First click of element doesn't work, second click does

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

https://alexkchapman.com/Vans.html

On any of the three images (and on mobile the nav button) on my site, the first click doesn't work, but following clicks do. Console is logging that a click is registered, but the image doesn't change.

Here's the relevant js:

```
var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
/* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
var slideId = ["slides1", "slides2", "slides3"];
showSlides(1, 0);
showSlides(1, 1);
showSlides(1, 2);

function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
  console.log(n);
}

function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]);
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not at an external site (which will probably be fixed when you get an answer to the question, so is useless for future readers).

Comment: It also helps detailing the exact steps to reproduce the issue

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but you need to put the initial calls to `showSlides()` in the `window.onload` function. You're calling them before the slides are loaded into the DOM, so it gets an error trying to set the style of `x[0]`.

Comment: I don't understand how `n` is being used. In `plusSlides()` it's the amount to increment the slide index by. But in `showSlides()` you're comparing it to the number of elements with the class. Why would you compare an increment with the total number?

Comment: You probably just want `if (slideIndex[no] > x.length) { slideIndex[no] = 1; }`

Comment: Why does the slide index wrap around to 1, not 0?

Answer (score 1):

So your code is not that bad but you should select slides by js class selector and the final code will look like this:
(I recommend using this code not your's because your code is complicated)

```js
// var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
// /* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
// var slideId = ["slides1", "slides2", "slides3"];
// showSlides(1, 0);
// showSlides(1, 1);
// showSlides(1, 2);
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');
var slideIndex = 0;

function plusSlides() {
  slideIndex++;
  showSlides(slideIndex);
}

function showSlides(Index) {
    if (Index >= slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (Index < 0) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    slides[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
            <div class="slides fade"><img src="img/header.jpg" width="100%"></div>
            <div class="slides fade"><img src="img/header1.jpg" width="100%"></div>
            <div class="slides fade"><img src="img/header2.jpg" width="100%"></div>
            <div class="slides fade"><img src="img/header3.jpg"     width="100%"></div>
</div>
```

Problems in your code are explained in comments:

```js
// Select slides via class!!!!!!!!!!!!

// var slideIndex = [1, 1, 1];
// /* Class the members of each slideshow group with different CSS classes */
// var slideId = ["slides1", "slides2", "slides3"];
// showSlides(1, 0);
// showSlides(1, 1);
// showSlides(1, 2);


// You only need to increment slideIndex and run showSlides again
function plusSlides(n, no) {
  showSlides(slideIndex[no] += n, no);
  console.log(n);
}

// here you only have to hide every slide and show the one with the index of slideIndex
function showSlides(n, no) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName(slideId[no]); // big mistake
//   every thing below is fine
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex[no] = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex[no] = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
//   execpt this line
  x[slideIndex[no] - 1].style.display = "block";
// should be like this
//   x[slideIndex].style.display = "block";
}
```